# How do I make JavaScript file paths relative to the current file directory?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

JavaScript file paths are relative to displayed page. How do I make JavaScript file paths relative to the current file directory?

For instance, I include a file `sh/shThemeDefault.css` into `footer.php` (there are under the same directory: `wordpress/wp-content/themes/`) by:

```
<script src="sh/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

While accessing a post (say `http://example.com/post-A`),

`sh/shCore.js` will be extended as `http://example.com/post-A/sh/shCore.js`, reporting **not found** error.

The right absolute path is `http://example.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sh/shCore.js`.

---

PS: I am installing [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html) by placing the following codes before `/body` in `footer.php`:

```
<link href="./sh/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./sh/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="./sh/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./sh/shAutoloader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader(
    ['python', 'py', 'sh/shBrushPython.js'],
    ['java', 'sh/shBrushJava.js'],
    ['bash','shell','sh/shBrushBash.js'],
    ['css','sh/shBrushCss.js'],
    ['sql','sh/shBrushSql.js'],
    ['latex', 'tex','sh/shBrushLatex.js.js'],
    ['plain', 'text','sh/shBrushPlain.js'],
    ['php','sh/shBrushPhp.js'],
    ['js','jscript','javascript','sh/shBrushJScript.js'],
    ['xml', 'xhtml', 'xslt', 'html', 'xhtml','sh/shBrushXml.js']
);
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like a CSS file, not a JS file...

Comment: @rnevius `<script src="sh/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` encounters the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be including CSS and JS files directly in your WordPress templates. Rather, you should be enqueueing them properly (in *functions.php*) via [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style):

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/shThemeDefault.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

This will completely eliminate the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Would you please set aside some time to have a look my edited question (below the horizontal line `PS:...`).

Answer (score 2):

In Wordpress you can use the following code to get the template directory: 
`<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>`

In your case will be something like:

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/sh/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to include resources that are intended to be included in/over-ridden by the child theme.